# Are microphones with flatter frequency response charts better at picking up frequencies?

Tags: frequency, microphone

I am doing an experiment where we measure the frequency using computer microphones and use Audacity to find the peak frequency. If there was a sound at 1kHz, would a better microphone pick up the frequency better and the graph would show a value closer to 1kHz, while a worse microphone would be off, or would the two be the same?

Comment: Please clarify in your question, what you mean by "pickup the freq. better" and "off". I'm assuming, you might mean to ask whether the recorded frequency would differ from the actual frequency of the sound? Most likely a cheap mic would be nearly as good as an expensive one to *identify* the frequency. The poor (not flat) frequency response of a cheap mic will mostly attenuate certain frequencies, but not really change their frequency. (There are other factors probably, the distortion of bad mic might still complicate things?)

Comment: I think you need to define "better at picking up"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general, the frequency-measurement would be quite accurate even with a low-quality microphone. This would only be affected by the accuracy of the clock used to control the sampling in the analog-to-digital converter.

Even without looking for specifications of various sound-cards, we can be pretty sure that this tolerance is below 0.5%, since the human ear is very sensitive to changes in frequency (pitch), and a 0.5% error would be quite noticable to a trained ear.

The main thing a better microphone could provide, is less noise and a flatter frequency response. This would allow you to more accuratly compare the amplitude of the signal at 1 kHz vs. the signal at other frequencies. However, if all you care about is the accuracy of the pitch, the computer microphone should be accurate enough. If it isn't, a better microphone probably won't help. You would need specialist equipment.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually find measurements of how accurate different audio interfaces are at measuring absolute frequency online.  This review for example notes that the product measured accurate to 0.0018% of absolute frequency:  http://nwavguy.blogspot.com/2011/05/fiio-e7-usb-dac-amp.html

For a 1KHz tone, you would be off by 0.018 Hz (18 milliHertz).  Clocks are generally very accurate in audio equipment, so provided the microphone can hear anything at all you should be able to measure frequency quite accurately. Of course for some applications even this might not be enough and you would provide your own reference clock of suitable accuracy, but given how cheap consumer audio products are they're a good choice if you can make them work.

Answer (score 0):

Poor frequency response *could* cause a problem under one circumstance: that it was so awful that a fundamental frequency simply got lost in the noise.

Consider a mic with a really horrible frequency response curve, something like this:

[image]

So let's assume you have a tone a frequency A, but due to the mic's terrible frequency response, it's ignored as just noise. But we'll assume it has a pretty strong second overtone (two octaves up) which lands at B. Because of the peak in the frequency response there, that's the frequency that gets detected and reported, rather than the fundamental that you really cared about.

With most real microphones, this should be almost entirely hypothetical though.

The only exceptions I can think of are special purpose microphones designed for specific instruments, with the specific intent of ignoring anything outside that instrument's frequency range, on the assumption that it *must* be noise. But those aren't particularly common to start with, and generally if you have one, you know what it's for, and wouldn't use it with some entirely different instrument.